# dependent:destroy throwing error with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm new to Postgres and I'm getting this error when testing the destroy action for a blog-type application.  It seems like the problem is that `works`, rather than `work`, is being called for a given Author when it's destroyed - as in it's being pluralized, but I'm not sure why that is.

```
Author.rb  
has_many :works, :dependent => :destroy
```

Error:

```
AuthorsController::destroy#test_0001_deletes the author:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column works.author_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "works".* FROM "works"  WHERE "works"."author_id" = $...
                                             ^
: SELECT "works".* FROM "works"  WHERE "works"."author_id" = $1  ORDER BY works.id ASC
```

Test:

```
 it "deletes the author" do
   assert_difference 'Author.count', -1 do
     delete :destroy, :id => author.id
   end
 end
```

Controller:

```
def destroy
  @author.destroy
  redirect_to authors_path
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that Postgres is complaining about is that it can't find a column called `author_id` on your `works` table, and as a result, it won't be able to find the corresponding `works` for a given `Author`.

If you haven't already, you'll need to add a migration to add an `author_id` column to `Work`.